# Route User Role Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I'm very confused on this situation. I have two routes with on resource name.

```
Route::resource('product', 'Product\AreaManagerProductController');
Route::resource('product', 'Product\SystemAdminProductController');
```

I need to make it as one because I have a contextual binding.

```
$this->app->when(AreaManagerProductController::class)
          ->needs(ProductInterface::class)
          ->give(AreaManagerProductRepository::class);

           $this->app->when(SystemAdminProductController::class)
          ->needs(ProductInterface::class)
          ->give(SystemAdminProductRepository::class);
```

The contextual binding works fine... but I need to change my route like this.

```
Route::resource('product_area_manager', 'Product\AreaManagerProductController');
Route::resource('product_system_admin', 'Product\SystemAdminProductController');
```

I created `ProductController` and some kind of weird solution.

```
public function index(){

        //Create a conditional statement base on user

        return app('App\Http\Controllers\Product\AreaManagerProductController')->index();

    }
```

It may work but it doesn't trigger the middleware... What could be the best practice on this situation. TY

Comment: You should not have same name of your route `Route::resource('product', 'Product\AreaManagerProductController');` like product. you should use different for every route

Comment: as @NikhilRadadiya said .. you cant declare a two routes with the same name .. what you can do is extend the controller to the other one .. `Route::resource('product', 'Product\AreaManagerProductController');` then in your AreaManagerProductController you can do, `class AreaManagerProductController extends SystemAdminProductController`

Comment: I know it won't work with two same name route resource... I'll try to extend the `ProductController` and see if I can make it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have your Route like this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'product', 'namespace' => 'Product', 'middleware' => '<your middleware>'], function() {

        Route::resource('area_manager', 'AreaManagerController');
        Route::resource('system_admin', 'SystemAdminController');
});
```

The reason I grouped the route is to reduce redundancy, and the reason i removed Product from the controller name is, as there is a `namespace Product` already, there is no need of long Class names.

If you wan to access some methods in the `AreaManagerController` and `SystemAdminController` just extend the `ProductController` to these Controllers.

If you want to add some specific `middleware` for the actions inside these controllers, I have added a `middleware` clause in the `route group` which will affect to these controllers, if not needed just remove it.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I think this is the only way... I've been thinking about it lately but I'm still finding other ways. I will accept your answer if I can't find one... Thanks for helping.

Comment: Thanks @Rbex , Just to organize and easy understanding of the code i used to write in this pattern .

Comment: Yeah, it would be great if we can just `Route::resource(Auth::User()->roles->first->name, Auth::User()->roles->first->name . 'Controller')`. I have tried it... it doesn't work.

Comment: @Rbex  It may throw a fatal error if you doesn't add `Auth Middleware` before accessing `Auth::User()` in routes. please be sure there is a `Auth Middleware` added before using `Auth` Facade

Comment: Yeah I understand your code and it's working... I mean this code would be great `Route::resource(Auth::User()->roles->first->name, Auth::User()->roles->first->name . 'Controller')` or something similar like this. Thanks I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Rbex, I just gave you a reminder to add the Auth middleware , Thanks Once Again :)